# What's the purpose of the Room of Doom?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, marauders-map

During the film version of *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, I noticed when Harry was looking for Peter Pettigrew by following his name on the [Marauder's Map](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marauder%27s_Map) in the hallways of Hogwarts Castle at night, he passes a circle-shaped room called [Room of Doom](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Room_of_Doom)!

[image: Room of Doom]

The HP Wikia doesn't really say much about this room other than acknowledging its existence. But with such an ominous name, I was wondering if there is any other information out there about this room? **What is its purpose and/or what has it been used for?**

Comment: It's since been renamed to the Room of Call of Duty

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## ‘The Room of Doom’ may just be the Marauders’ own name for it.

There’s no mention of any place in Hogwarts called ‘the Room of Doom’ anywhere but displayed on the Marauder’s Map in the movie “Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, and on the official replica of the Map that’s sold as merchandise. What seems to be the most likely explanation for this, when considering the other labels used on the Map, is that it’s the Marauders’ own term, and the Room itself is not actually called the Room of Doom. Near to the Room of Doom is a room shown as ‘the Vestibule of Mischief’, which also seems an unlikely name for a room in Hogwarts.

[image]

Both ‘the Room of Doom’ and ‘the Vestibule of Mischief’ seem to be names that the Marauders themselves would invent rather than the actual names of those rooms. Other things depicted on the map are also labeled in a way that the Marauders would’ve found useful rather than by proper names. There’s a room labeled ‘Beware— Boggart in this closet’, a passageway labeled ‘Beware of moving staircases’, and both a room and a passageway labeled ‘Peeves may lurk here’, all of which are clearly meant to remind the Marauders of these hazards rather than being names.

[image]

Therefore, it seems most likely that the Room of Doom was only called that by the Marauders.

## The purpose of the room, or why they’d label it that, isn’t known.

Exactly what room the ‘Room of Doom’ really is isn’t clear - its intended purpose isn’t known. However, presumably there was something about the room that made the Marauders consider it to contain ‘doom’ in some way, whether doom to them specifically, like a teacher that would want to stop their mischief,  or more general danger. There’s certainly a reason for its name, but it’s not known what exactly that reason would be nor can it be logically deduced from the name itself.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! (I do wonder though since Newt's name appears on the map too during the course of the film, if somehow these rooms, names withstanding, will be tied into Fantastic Beasts somehow??? I know there is the whole Newt writing the whole 'special edition' thing that DD claims is the reason for him being there, but I can't help to think there could be more to this, since it appears the deathly hallows (and other things pertaining to Riddle) are important to Fantastic Beasts' story line too...

Comment: Umm... I've nothing to back it up so a completely wild guess: "Prowling passage" sounds like the area that Mrs Norris might be keeping an eye out for things (don't remember though if she's specifically described as "prowling") and "Room of Doom" sounds like a name the Marauder's would give Filch's office.

Comment: @JonClements that's an interesting theory, I like it! :)

Comment: @bellatrix Unless there is some update about this in 'Fantastic Beasts' film or film-related material, I will check you off  and keep yours as the best answer!

Comment: @DarthLocke I did some more research, and found further evidence that the Marauders labeled things in ways they found useful, not always their proper names. Thanks for accepting my answer! :)

Comment: The two images you posted actually show identical maps with some of the names changed. The "Room of Doom" is labeled as "Peeves May Lurk Here" in the other image. Similarly, the "Vestibule of Mischief" is now the "Divination Stairwell", and the "Prowling passage" is now the "Way to Transfiguration". The other visible names appear the same.

Comment: @DavidK They’re both pictures of the official replica of the Marauders’ Map, it seems to be a matter of how it’s folded. [Here](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CF1I_GT0YKg/U5kxNUQunrI/AAAAAAAAGOw/5K81t8fP9IM/s1600/1_a_harrypotterworld_23.jpg) is a picture of the Marauder’s Map showing the places in both pictures.

Comment: @Bellatrix - One has to wonder if one should fold the map differently at different times of day, perhaps. Unless there's an existing explanation for why to fold the map differently.